# write post error in the sort

Tags: php, mysql, http-post, user-profile, posting

hello this codes is for write post in user profile the codes its right and without any mistake but i have error when in write post the new post will be the last post i mean i have erro in sortting how can i fixed to make the new post its first post like  facebook or any social network

```
<?php
if (isset ($_SESSION['user_login']))
{
    $user = $_SESSION["user_login"];`enter code here`
}
else
{
$user = "";
}
    $date_added = date ("Y-m-d");
    $added_by =$user;
    $user_posted_to = '';   


$post = @$_POST['post'];

if ($post != '')
   {
    $date_added = date ("Y-m-d");
    $added_by = $user;
    $user_posted_to = $user;
    $sqlCommand = "INSERT INTO posts (id,body,date_added,added_by,user_posted_to) VALUES ('','$post','$date_added','$added_by','$user_posted_to')";
    $query = mysql_query ($sqlCommand) or die (mysql_error());

    $getposts = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE user_posted_to ='$user' ") or die(mysql_error());
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($getposts)) 
                    {
                    $id = $row['id'];
                    $body = $row['body'];   
                    $date_added = $row['date_added'];
                    $added_by = $row['added_by'];
                    $user_posted_to = $row['user_posted_to'];  

                 echo "

                    <div class='posted_by'>
                    Posted by:
                                            <a href='$added_by'>$added_by</a> on $date_added</div>
                                            <br />
                                            <div  style='max-width: 600px;'>
                                            $body<br /><p />
                                            </div></br>
                                            <hr />
                    ";
                    }
   }
else
{

    $getposts = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE user_posted_to ='$user' ") or die(mysql_error());
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($getposts)) 
                    {
                    $id = $row['id'];
                    $body = $row['body'];   
                    $date_added = $row['date_added'];
                    $added_by = $row['added_by'];
                    $user_posted_to = $row['user_posted_to'];  

                 echo "

                    <div class='posted_by'>
                    Posted by:
                                            <a href='$added_by'>$added_by</a> on $date_added</div>
                                            <br />
                                            <div  style='max-width: 600px;'>
                                            $body<br /><p />
                                            </div></br>
                                            <hr />
                    ";
                    }
}



?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$getposts = mysql_query("
    SELECT * 
    FROM posts 
    WHERE user_posted_to ='$user'
    order by id desc
") or die(mysql_error());
```